# I create a context API that and there is productstate in which i creted the different funtions but its return an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

The error return in productstae is
ERROR in [eslint]
src\context\product\ProductState.js
Line 34:13:  Unexpected use of 'name'      no-restricted-globals
Line 35:20:  'description' is not defined  no-undef
Line 36:14:  'price' is not defined        no-undef
Line 37:16:  'category' is not defined     no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

This is my productContext.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
const ProductContext= createContext();

export default ProductContext;
```

This is my ProductState.js I created all function here but the error came in where I created the object newImage There is throw the error that its not define .my routes are working in backen beacause i test my APIs with postman.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProductContext from "./ProductContext";

const ProductState = (props) => {
    const host = "http://localhost:5000"
    const productInitial = []

    const [product, setProduct] = useState(productInitial);
    //Add Note
    const addProduct=async(name,description,price,category,image)=>{
        //TODO API CALL
        let url = `${host}/api/Imageprac/upload`
        //Api Call
        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'auth-token': "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJlZThmMGI4NmU1YzQ5NDZkM2I3NWQ1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1OTgwMTM1NX0.NdR38S1oby9mSzl1zTH-LYYavsJGjwq6OWsPP_q3YvI"
            
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({name,description,price,category,image}) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        });
        const json= response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects

    }
//logic to add a note
console.log("adding a new note");

const newImage={
    "_id": "63304097cc95e936a974bd6e",
    "user": "62ee8f0b86e5c4946d3b75d5",
    "name": name,
    "description": description,
    "price": price,
    "category":category,
    "image":Object,
    "date": "2022-08-25T10:26:57.324Z",
    "__v": 0    

}
setProduct(product.concat(newImage));


  return (
<ProductContext.Provider  value={{ product,addProduct}}>
{props.children}
</ProductContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ProductState;
```

This is my App.js code

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  
} from "react-router-dom";
import About from './components/About';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Signup from './components/Signup';
import AdminForm from './components/AdminForm';
import Loginagain from './components/Loginagain';
import Signupagain from './components/Signupagain';
import ProductState from './context/product/ProductState';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <ProductState>
    <Router>
    <Navbar/>
    <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
    <Route path='/about' element={<About/>}/>
    <Route path='/login' element={<Loginagain/>}/>
    <Route path='/signup' element={<Signupagain/>}/>
    <Route path='/adminpanel' element={<AdminForm/>}/>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    </ProductState>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my route that used in backend node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const router = express.Router();
const multer=require('multer');
const fetchuser = require('../middleware/fethuser');
const imageModel=require('../models/imageModel');
const app = express()

//storage

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'uploads',
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null,file.originalname)
    }
  })

  const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('testImage');

  router.post('/upload',fetchuser,async(req,res)=>{
     upload(req,res,(err)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            const newImage= new imageModel({
                
                name:req.body.name,
                description:req.body.description,
                price:req.body.price,
                category:req.body.category,
                user: req.user.id,
                image:{
                    data:req.file.filename,
                    contentType:'image/png '
                }
                

            })
            newImage.save()
            .then(()=>res.send("succesfully uploaded")).catch((err)=>console.log(err))
        }
     })
  });

  module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Try to solve the problem yourself first, the error messages from `eslint` are generally useful and should point you to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your eslint error messages:

```
Unexpected use of 'name' no-restricted-globals Line 35:20:
'description' is not defined no-undef Line 36:14:
'price' is not defined no-undef Line 37:16:
'category' is not defined no-undef
```

It's caused by your `setProduct` section sitting **outside** the `addProduct` method, as theres an erroneous `{`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ProductContext from "./ProductContext";

const host = "http://localhost:5000";

const ProductState = (props) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  //Add Note
  const addProduct = async (name, description, price, category, image) => {
    let url = `${host}/api/Imageprac/upload`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.

      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token":
          "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiNjJlZThmMGI4NmU1YzQ5NDZkM2I3NWQ1In0sImlhdCI6MTY1OTgwMTM1NX0.NdR38S1oby9mSzl1zTH-LYYavsJGjwq6OWsPP_q3YvI",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({ name, description, price, category, image }), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    });

    // TODO: do something with this json response
    const json = response.json();
    
    //logic to add a note
    console.log("adding a new note");

    const newImage = {
      _id: "63304097cc95e936a974bd6e",
      user: "62ee8f0b86e5c4946d3b75d5",
      name: name,
      description: description,
      price: price,
      category: category,
      image: Object,
      date: "2022-08-25T10:26:57.324Z",
      __v: 0,
    };
    setProduct(product.concat(newImage));
  };

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ product, addProduct }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: yes from this snippet